Flink Sql query to use UNNEST and create temp table
I am working on converting the Spark SQL query into Flink SQL. Working Spark SQL query is :
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW tempView AS 
SELECT 
    event.user_id AS userId, 
    event.code AS code, 
    test12.id AS id, 
    test12 
FROM 
    user_interaction_data_table
LATERAL VIEW 
    explode(tests_explode) AS test12 
WHERE 
    event.user_id IS NOT NULL 
    AND CAST(event.user_id AS INT) > 0 
    AND event.event_timestamp > 1710806400000 
    AND event.event_timestamp < 1710817200000;

I have tried to convert it into Flink SQL using Flink's Table API:
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW tempView AS 
SELECT 
    event.user_id AS userId, 
    event.code AS code, 
    test12.id AS id, 
    test12 
FROM 
    test_event
UNNEST(tests_explode) AS test12 
WHERE 
    event.user_id IS NOT NULL 
    AND CAST(event.user_id AS INT) > 0 
    AND event.event_timestamp > 1710806400000 
    AND event.event_timestamp < 1710817200000;

But I am getting error that

test12 is not recognized

Note: tests_explode is a nested struct with multiple fields inside it.
tests_explode
|--id
|--field2

Can someone please help review the Flink Sql query and help how to fix it.
I want to make sure that as a subsequent query, I can run :
SELECT test12.another_field from tempView;


You could do something more like this:
SELECT 
    event.user_id AS userId, 
    event.code AS code, 
    id, 
    field2,
    another_field 
FROM 
    test_event
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(tests_explode) AS test12 (id, field2, another_field)
WHERE 
    event.user_id IS NOT NULL 
    AND CAST(event.user_id AS INT) > 0 
    AND event.event_timestamp > 1710806400000 
    AND event.event_timestamp < 1710817200000;


Caused by: org.apache.calcite.runtime.CalciteContextException: From line 1, column 82 to line 1, column 91: Column 'test12' not found in any table
This is what I see when I tried CROSS JOIN.

I've revised my answer.

Was thinking if there is a way to add test12 so that i could maintain the struct as it is. Any suggestions like we did in spark?

Or maybe I can do as suggested above and if there is a way to create struct with all the fields because it seems STRUCT is not supported by Flink Sql as of now.

Flink SQL has a ROW type -- you should be able to create an embedded ROW. E.g., SELECT ROW(id, field2, another_field) FROM test_event CROSS JOIN ...
